# Plotly px.imshow show values in tiles

Tags: python, plotly

I create a heatmap with the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],
                    [[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0]]
                   ], dtype=np.uint8)
fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)
fig.show()
```

When I mouse over I can see the value of the "tile". I would like the value to be shown in the heatmap in each of the "tiles", is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use annotations to display the respective values, since this cannot be done directly in the graph drawing.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],
                    [[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0]]
                   ], dtype=np.uint8)

fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)

for i,r in enumerate(img_rgb):
    for k,c in enumerate(r):
        fig.add_annotation(x=k,y=i,
                           text='rgb:{}:{}:{}'.format(c[0],c[1],c[2]),
                           showarrow=False,
                          )
fig.show()
```

[image]